# Authentication for users not in Active directory

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010

I have a web application which is using Windows Authentication. I need to add a log-on layer with a field for password(no username) for users which are not in active directory. How should I proceed?

Comment: Read up on FBA - Forms Based Authentication - also consider non-programming questions for sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Password-only (i.e., no username) authentication is not a good idea, as it only provides a trivial boundary against global access and removes the possibility of accountability, permissioning, and scalability.  Would all of your username-less users be given the same password?  If so, how [wc]ould you handle changing the password for all of the users?  If you give each new person their own password, wouldn't you need to keep track of ownership?  Isn't that just one step away from assigning each person a username and going on to implement real authentication?  It would be a [mistake to even attempt access control on a per-password basis](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Phantom-Password.aspx).

You should strongly reconsider.  Giving your users their own AD accounts specifically for site authentication, but that are not permissioned for anything else on your system, is a **much** better approach, as it does not limit future scalability/evolution and will provide actual security.

Comment: The application is going to be used in a some retail stores. And password would be the same for a given store users. I just need to make sure that no random person can access the application. All users in a store will have the same password.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Authentication requires a username and a password to do the authentication. Without a username, it can't be done. You'll either need a second web application with a custom authentication provider or consider just creating a slave AD account for these types of users to use and lock down the permissions that way.